# Setting bigger image and bigger icon on tab bar

Tags: ios, ios7, tabbar

How to increase tab bar height and tab bar icon size in addition to remove tab bar separation line?

i did something to increase size but icon size still same.

```
[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuBar_bg.png"]];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the size of the icons. E.g: if it is 30x30, try 45x45.